# Errno 13 Permission denied 'C:\\Program files\\Python310\\CS project.py'

Tags: python, windows, exception, cmd, path

I am unable to understand what the problem is, some parts of the code are working but some parts were not so to check it I intentionally put errors but the interpreter is not raising any issues. I recently reinstalled python as I was facing issues while installing modules and now I think while sorting out that problem I did something that is the reason for this problem.[there is division by zero which should raise an exception but it does not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DBKp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to run your python script from a folder that prohibits access from a non-administrator.
Either move your script `CS project.py` to a folder that you can run (for example, your Desktop), or run your `cmd` (or `powershell`) with Administrator permissions.

Comment: In general, when you encounter `Permission Denied` error, you should try to run the program with Administrator permissions *Only if you trust this program*.